# selenium cannot locate button

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

I try to automatically click on a given `downloadButton` *id* but it doesn't work on this demo website https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/progress-bar.

Chromedriver opens, then nothing happens on the website and at some point it closes due to timeout I imagine ?

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\x\Dropbox\PC\Documents\Python Project\selenium tutorial\tutorial1.py", line 22, in <module>  
    my_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "downloadButton")
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

I do some implicit wait supposing that the button doesn't exist but it won't work.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

ser = Service("C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)

driver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/progress-bar/")

# Wait for checkbox to be located
button_wait = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downloadButton'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(button_wait)

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
# my_element = driver.find_element_by_id('downloadButton')
my_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "downloadButton")
my_element.click()
```

chrome-version 98.0.4758.81

Comment: Let me know if my answer resolved your problem

Comment: I just realised the checker existence to accept answer, I was just upvoting them so far... I will fix this right now :) 

Thank you for your answer, I'll check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are trying to access is inside an iframe.
So you first have to switch into that iframe in order to access elements inside it.
Like the following:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

ser = Service("C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/progress-bar/")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.demo-frame.lazyloaded")))

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "downloadButton"))).click()
```

When finished working inside the iframe you will have to switch back to a defaul content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: chromedriver opens, the page loads waits 2 second I guess then shuts down. The button isn't clicked, no callback nor error

Comment: I surrounded your code within a function and made an inifinite while true loop at the end, it works :)

Comment: Strange, I suppose it work without loops... What code have you surrounded with a loop to make it work?

Comment: nevermind, I am new to selenium, it seems normal that it shut downs immediatly, I added some time.sleep() to appreciate the html manipulation.